# Trying to apply an authorisation filter in all my controllers but IAuthorizationHandler is not being used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I try to define an authorization policy to be applied in all methods of all my controllers. I am trying to follow the [guidelines given here, in "Authorization for specific endpoints" subsection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code) to substitute my previous `AuthorizeFilter` but it does not work.

In my `Startup` I have:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization();
});
```

In `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureADBearer(options => this.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddRequirements(new MyRequirement(MyParams))
        .Build();
});
(...)
    services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, MyAuthorizationHandler>();
```

And I have a Requirement:

```
public class MyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public EntityType MyParams { get; private set; }

    public MyRequirement(MyParams myParams) { MyParams = myParams; }
}
```

and a Handler:

```
public class MyAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyAuthorizationHandler> logger;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public MyAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILogger<MyAuthorizationHandler> logger)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
    {
---> Some things. I don't get here when I debug.       
    }
}
```

In my controllers I do NOT put any decorator, because I want to apply this authorization policy to ALL my methods, and that's why I override the `DefaultPolicy`.

If I debug, I do not stop at the Handler as I expect. Actually, if I put a decorator `[Authorize]` in the controller, I do stop there but, as I mentioned, I'm trying to avoid having to write this decorator in all the controllers.

Why is is not working? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. In `ConfigureServices` in `startup`:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        "UserIsRegistered",
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddRequirements(new RegistrationRequirement())
            .Build());
});
```

Then I defined the `RegistrationRequirement`:

```
 public class RegistrationRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
 {
 }
```

Then I defined the `RegistrationAuthorizationHandler`

```
public class RegistrationAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RegistrationRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RegistrationRequirement requirement)
        {
---> LOGIC I WANT TO CHECK
            if (WHATEVER)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

and finally in `Configure` in the `startup` again:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization("UserIsRegistered");
});
```

To sum up, my main problem it was using `MapDefaultControllerRoute` instead of `MapControllers`...

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the `[Authorize]` attribute is required in order to use even the default policy. What I normally do when I need to protect all my endpoints in this way is to create an abstract base controller with this attribute and then have my other controllers inherit from this.

For example:

Base controller

```
[Authorize]
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller //use Controller for mvc controller or ControllerBase for api controller
{
//base controller methods and properties
}
```

Other controllers:

```
public class MyOtherController : MyBaseController 
{
//controller methods and properties
}
```

Comment: That's a good trick, indeed. But previously I was using an AuthorizeFilter which had to be declared only once in the Startup and in the reference I provided it was explained how to substitute it (I think without having to add attributes...).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{         
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, MyAuthorizationHandler>();

    services.AddControllersWithViews(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddRequirements(new MyRequirement(MyParams))
            .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });

    services.AddDbContext<MvcProj3Context>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcProj3Context")));
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    });
}
```